# how to mock file write in append mode 'ab' using unittest python

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, python-3.6

```
    def test_pipe_out_to_mocked_existing_file(self):
    '''
    Verify the filedata append functionality  
    using mock open
    '''
    with patch('builtins.open', mock_open(read_data=b'This is first data')) as mock_file:
        #handle.exists.return_value = True
        with patch('os.path.exists', return_value=True):
            #mock_file.write.reset_mock()  # Reset the mock_file.write() call count
            self.controller.out(base_name=self.base_name, data=b'This is second data')
            mock_file.assert_called_with(self.file_path,'ab')
            handle = mock_file.return_value.__enter__.return_value
            handle.write.assert_called_with(b'This is second data')
            self.assertEqual(handle.write.call_count, 1)
            read_data = handle.read()
            self.assertEqual(read_data, b'This is first dataThis is second data')
            # clear up the directory created by 'out'
            os.rmdir(self.parameters['filepath'])
```

The problem with above code is that 'read_data' in assertEqual is always b'This is first data' instead of b'This is first dataThis is second data'

Can anyone please help me to find whats wrong in the code?
Thank you!